# How can I traverse through deeply nested div without class attributes

Tags: jquery

This is what I tried but it is selecting all the `a` tags that are in other `divs`

`$('div:has( > div > div > a[href*="hello/"])').css( "color", "blue");` but this selects every `<a>`. But I need `<a>`'s i.e. within deeply nested `<div> <a href="hello/..">`

```
<body> 
 <div class="headers"> 
   <div> 
     <a href="welcome/"> welcomes one</a>
     <a href="welcome/"> welcomes two</a>
   </div>
 </div>     
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>  
      <div> 
       <div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div> 
       <div>
       </div>
       <div class="columns">
        <div>
         <div> <a href="hello/one"> once</a></div>
         <div> <a href="hello/two"> twice</a></div>
         <div> <a href="hello/three"> thrice</a></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't just `$('.columns a')` or `$('a[href*="hello/"]')`  ??? .... Or you just need the deepest `a` element ?

Comment: *"but this selects every `<a>`"* no it doesn't... it selects the div that contains them all.

Comment: `$('.columns a') `or ` $('a[href*="hello/"]')` they both select all the `a ` elements. The deepest a elements nested within deepest div is needed.  these ones: `<div> <a href="hello/one"> once</a></div>
         <div> <a href="hello/two"> twice</a></div>
         <div> <a href="hello/three"> thrice</a></div>`

Comment: To me this looks like an X/Y problem. You need to be able to select some arbitrary elements to solve problem X, and thus problem Y is created, because you can't figure out how to select them. Why do you need to select them, and why do they not have some kind of class on the anchor you can use or on a parent element? We can give you a selector that would work for the very specific case you've given, but it will likely not work in the actual code you have, or will be brittle and break the moment you change something else.

Answer (score -1):

This ensures that the div is last div child (deeply nested):

```
  var start = $('.headers').parents('div').length;
$('.headers a').each(function(){
      if($(this).parents('div:not(.headers)').length-start>5)
          $(this).css( "color", "green");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dxdL22e2/6/)

Comment: I edited the answer. It was because of the extra `)` at the end of the selector.

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: what about this? counting the depth

Comment: Don't work for deepest https://jsfiddle.net/dxdL22e2/8/ ... I'm working on a solution based on parents length too ... but it's tricky